# Inno Setup - How to fix too long path in StatusLabel in TUninstallProgressForm

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation, pascalscript

In Inno Setup, I want show a text when user uninstall my app. But the text is too long so it can't show all.

Here is the code:

```pascal
UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.WordWrap := True;
UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.AutoSize := True;
UninstallProgressForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'C:\ProgramData\longpath\12345678987654321\abcdefghiklm\12345678987654321\abcdefghiklm\12345678987654321\abcdefghiklm';
```

[image]

How can I display all text or display text like: `C:\ProgramData\longpath\...\abcdefghiklm`

Comment: (I have posted a more verbose answer to the duplicate question now)